# React.js - Static files are cached and loading from service worker

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

When I do any changes in my CSS file and do a build, a new CSS bundle file is created.

Build One

[image: Build One]

Console.log of Build One

[image: Console log 1]

Build Two

[image: Build 2]

Console.log of Build Two

[image]

If you see in the second build the CSS file name is changed from **main.1012bf29.chunk.css** to **main.2ff4e3dd.chunk.css**

But if you see the console log for both the build is same, the CSS file of the first build is cached.

Expected output: On every build, the cache needs to be cleared.

Note: I have enabled PWA in my react app. React version is 16.7.0, I have created my project using the create-react-app command

Comment: As far as I know, when an installed event was fired in a service worker, it adds all the static assets into the cache. If you want to delete a cache, you can probably use `caches.delete(cacheName)` and `caches.keys()` for [cache management](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/building-progressive-web/9781491961643/ch04.html).

Comment: I think the index.html file is cached and even after so many changes, I took a build, even then the old CSS files are getting loaded. If I do a hard refresh or clearing the cache it is working. How can I solve this problem in React.js?